# Default value in a HashMap for a custom class in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, constructor

I want to use a HashMap in C++ where the objects stored are instances of a custom class. This custom class only has a constructor with one parameter that I need to set.

The HashMap allows to set the default value of the objects inside it via its constructor: `HashMap(const mapped_type &v)`.

The problem is that I am not sure how to use it.

Let's say my custom class is called `Foo` and requires to give an int to its constructor.

If I want all the objects in the `HashMap` to be instantiated with the value 3, should I do something like this?

```
HashMap<String, Foo> myMap(Foo(3));
```

Does it require to implement a copy constructor in `Foo`?

Edit: I Have to use that particular HashMap and therefore the given constructor to handle the default value.

Comment: Please show the code that you have so far (or a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
HashMap<String, Foo> myMap(Foo(3));
```

is supposed to work, you are creating a temp object of class Foo and binding it to the const Foo& that the HashMap takes at the constructor
This is allowed.

Now, if when inserting default values, HashMap is copying from some saved default Foo member, then yes, Foo will need a copy constructor.
Just remember that the compiler generates a copy constructor for you, and you should write your own only if you need some special care (like if some of the members are dynamically allocated)

Answer (score 1):

Define default constructor for foo:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo() {value = 3;};
    int value;
};
```

Using std, with std::string as key and foo as value:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, foo> hashMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, foo>();

std::cout << hashMap["newValue"].value;
```

It will output 3;

Comment: Giving 3 to Foo was just an example, in fact, I have to give it a pointer that may change (but must be shared by all objects in the HashMap). Moreover, I have to use that particular HashMap to store the data.

Comment: Ok, then you have to share a bit more about HashMap. It can be that it already does what you want, meaning when you try accessing object under a key that's not in HashMap it inserts a copy of default one and then returns it.

Comment: Yes, it indeed does that. My question was more about passing it "Foo(3)" for the default value and if it requires a copy constructor in Foo. So the question is more about C++ than this HashMap.

Comment: Copy constructor are created by default in C++, so you don't need new one.